# How to calculate cache misses for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, statistics, cache

I'm administering a server where a tool using a PostgreSQL runs. The tool takes care of most PostgreSQL configurations by itself, but I'm observing some performance problems. I could confirm at OS level that a **lot of I/O is taking place**, therefore I suspect that a lot of cache misses are taking place.

If you look for "cache miss" or "cache miss postgresql" or similar searches in the Internet, you will find a lot of references to "**cache_miss statistics**". But nowhere is explained how to get them! I kind of understood, that that value has to be calculated **subtracting hits from fetches**. But since I'm *no experienced DB admin*, I don't really understand with values are meant :-S

I found the [PostgreSQL - Monitoring Database Activity](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html) documentation, but I'm not sure if following formula is all I need:

```
cache_miss = "result_of" pg_stat_get_db_blocks_fetched(oid) - "result_of" pg_stat_get_db_blocks_hit(oid)
```

An explanation for **dummies** would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How large is the database? Does the database fit in memory? Are you checking vmstat / iostat on a cold boot? Remember that the database has to be loaded in memory before caching can be effective.

Comment: Unfortunately the DB will never fit in memory, because it is over 200GB big! =-O I didn't check vmstat/iostat on a cold boot and will have a look at it. But it would only give me the Kernel cache misses, isn't it? I'm starting to think that the DB cache missing is the field _blks_read_ from the view _pg_stat_database_

Answer (score 4):

I use this query to show `disk x cache` hits:

```
-- perform a "select pg_stat_reset();" when you want to reset counter statistics
with 
all_tables as
(
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  'all'::text as table_name, 
        sum( (coalesce(heap_blks_read,0) + coalesce(idx_blks_read,0) + coalesce(toast_blks_read,0) + coalesce(tidx_blks_read,0)) ) as from_disk, 
        sum( (coalesce(heap_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(idx_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(toast_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(tidx_blks_hit,0))  ) as from_cache    
    FROM    pg_statio_all_tables  --> change to pg_statio_USER_tables if you want to check only user tables (excluding postgres's own tables)
    ) a
WHERE   (from_disk + from_cache) > 0 -- discard tables without hits
),
tables as 
(
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  relname as table_name, 
        ( (coalesce(heap_blks_read,0) + coalesce(idx_blks_read,0) + coalesce(toast_blks_read,0) + coalesce(tidx_blks_read,0)) ) as from_disk, 
        ( (coalesce(heap_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(idx_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(toast_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(tidx_blks_hit,0))  ) as from_cache    
    FROM    pg_statio_all_tables --> change to pg_statio_USER_tables if you want to check only user tables (excluding postgres's own tables)
    ) a
WHERE   (from_disk + from_cache) > 0 -- discard tables without hits
)
SELECT  table_name as "table name",
    from_disk as "disk hits",
    round((from_disk::numeric / (from_disk + from_cache)::numeric)*100.0,2) as "% disk hits",
    round((from_cache::numeric / (from_disk + from_cache)::numeric)*100.0,2) as "% cache hits",
    (from_disk + from_cache) as "total hits"
FROM    (SELECT * FROM all_tables UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tables) a
ORDER   BY (case when table_name = 'all' then 0 else 1 end), from_disk desc
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there. So your "disk hits" can still be hitting the OS disk cache right? That is, it's hits to the shared buffers memory?

Comment: Yes! The "disk hits" value means that the tuple was not found in the database's sharedbuffers. But it doesn't necessarily mean that db went to disk to get the tuple. Sometimes it can get you a good clue, specially when you have a dedicated server, where almost entire memory is reserved to the sharedbuffers. In that case, if you have a high "disk hits" percentage, that surely means it's time to upgrade memory.

Comment: In the cases you have a shared server (and you can't "reserve" almost entire memory to sharedbuffers), and you have high "disk hits" percentage, it means the database is "racing" against the others process by the memory use, and depending of the memory use (by the other processes), it probably is going to the disk to get tuples. So, in one case or the other, you have to avoid high "disk hits" percentages.

Answer (score 1):

There is a paragraph in PostgreSql's documentation: ([Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html))

`Note: pg_stat_get_blocks_fetched minus pg_stat_get_blocks_hit gives the number of kernel read() calls issued for the table, index, or database; the number of actual physical reads is usually lower due to kernel-level buffering. The *_blks_read statistics columns use this subtraction, i.e., fetched minus hit.`

This may explain your doubt.